# registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

i have an ecommerce website it is running ok with localhost but as i am trying to run it on server getting this error is it necessary to register it on iis server when it is already on server ... after removing the authentication tag works fine on server but some of its fuctionality stops working ........... please help

Comment: <configuration>

  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="hasexaminationConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=testonline1904.db.9688736.hostedresource.com;Initial Catalog=testonline1904;User ID=test; Password='1234abc"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 0):

For actual answer you have to put some your code and specialy your web.config.

Problem is with your web.config element and you try to override some web.config element that not allow on server and specially if it is shared hosting.

You might have tried to do nested application on server and it create this type of issue.